How to remove an expired .me domain from GitHub Pages that was provided through the GitHub Student Pack?
I was using a free .me domain from Namecheap, which I got through the GitHub Student Pack. The domain has now expired, but every time I create a new repository and deploy it on GitHub Pages, the expired domain is automatically linked to the repository.
I've tried checking the settings under the "Pages" tab, but there's no custom domain listed. However, when I visit the repository's GitHub Pages, it still redirects to the expired domain.
I've also tried clearing DNS settings and caching on my browser, but the problem persists. How can I completely remove this expired domain from GitHub Pages and prevent it from being added to new repositories?
Thanks in advance for any help!
